# Internet Explorer gives table enormous negative width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following code, which essentially represents a button that hides/shows content.

The specific content I'd like to show is a table with two columns, each with a list. One of the lists has a special list style.

The problem is that when I click on the text to expand the body, IE makes the table have a width of something like -180,000px and expand way off the screen, with a huge scrollbar. If I collapse the body and expand it again, it works just fine.

```html
<style>
 ul {
  list-style: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAHAQMAAAD6aRWtAAAABlBMVEX///+AgIBizNOVAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABdJREFUeF49wSEBAAAAg7D3T4zkim30BCumBNn/PQx4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
 }
 .theBody {
  display: none;
 }
</style>

<div class="clicker">Click me</div>
<div class="theBody">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
   <ul>
     <li>x</li>
   </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
   <ol>
     <li>y</li>
   </ol>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(".clicker").click(function (e) {
  $(".theBody").toggle();
 });
</script>
```

You can see the result here (don't use the Stack-Overflow generated preview above, at least for me it does not repro there): http://output.jsbin.com/kesapinuxa/1/
(You have to wait a few seconds for the script to load and all, then click on the text while in IE 11).

I have boiled down the code to the essentials. If I remove the list style image, it works. If I remove the display:none initially, it works. If I remove either of the lists, it works. Even if I change the order of the columns, it works.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: *don't use the Stack-Overflow generated preview above* Why? It demonstrates the problem you're talking about. Is there something else going on that's not in the question?

Comment: For me it doesn't repro there in IE. Do you see it reproing the same massive scrollbar that the link I give does?

Comment: Strange, I can't seem to reproduce it in IE 11.0.9600.18282 using the JSBin or the snippet.

Comment: Try waiting about 5 seconds before clicking on the text in the JSBin. I've gotten several people to repro. I have IE 11.0.9600.18378

Comment: No dice on my end, perhaps it's a regression? I can't get Windows update to finish loading though, to try to update my IE VM. :-/

Comment: Yes, I got the huge scrollbar with IE 11.0.9600.18376

Comment: I've found that if I change the image to something else, but still use a data:image, the bug still happens. You might have found a straight up bug.

Comment: Even if I switch to an actual image it reproes for me.

Comment: I've got a very similar bug with IE9. The table width gets set to -0.01px and the tds are ~1800,000px wide. It seems related to an svg icon I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug, caused by an interaction of flexbox with table-like divs, and fixed it by adding a width to one of the wrappers. It isn't the same as your bug but maybe this will help anyone else stuck on this problem.

The x-field div would show a computed width in IE Developer Tools of -184070.03px (note the negative sign), but in Chrome it would flow properly and respect the 100% width property.

Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* All 6 of the below properties must be present for the bug to happen */
    .group {
        align-items: flex-start;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .x-field {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100% !important;
    }


    .wrap {
        /* width: 100%; */ /* This fixes it - uncomment */
    }

    /* add borders to visually see the bug without F12 */
    div.group {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .x-field {
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
</style>

<div class="group">
    <div class="wrap"> <!-- Removing this div fixes it, but my original markup requires this div so that's not a viable fix. -->
        <div class="x-field">Field</div>
    </div>
</div>
```